# turn up the dial

Tags: meaning, idioms

Usage example with [a context](http://finance.yahoo.com/news/putin-dead-soldiers-evidence-deceit-111500275.html):

> The restoration of Kiev's control over the border is critical, Blinken said. "Unless that happens and until that happens, Russia will always have, and President Putin will always have, the possibility to **turn up the dial** any time he wants," said Blinken, "sending weapons in, sending men in, materiel in, and reigniting the conflict."

What do you think this expression means and where you think it originated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the cited article is badly written - it has spelling and grammar errors, as well as non-standard usages like the one being asked about here. The writer is "mangling" a relatively common idiomatic usage...

> [**turn up the heat** (on someone or something)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/heat) (figurative, alternatively **turn the heat up...**)
>    *to put pressure on someone or something; apply additional pressure to someone or something.*

OP's cited usage is a misguided attempt at a "extended" metaphoric reference, where the underlying ***heat*** = (increasing) tension in a (potential) conflict is indirectly referenced through the *control **dial*** (for a cooker, heating system, etc.). The intended meaning will be obvious to a native speaker, but the usage itself isn't idiomatically standard.

Answer (score 4):

You can turn a dial up or down. See [defintion 2](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/turn+up), used metaphorically. Turning a dial *up* increases the intensity. Search for *turn up* on the same page.

So it is a *phrasal verb* with a metaphorical meaning. This has lead to *[dial up](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dial+up)* to have the same meaning (scroll to phrasal verb *dial up*), but this is not as common as *turn up* used in this sense. Note *turn up* also has other meanings. One is to *appear*. Another is a [vegetable](http://urbanext.illinois.edu/veggies/turnip.cfm).

Comment: The reference to *turn up* as a vegetable is a joke. But the pronounciation of *turn up* and *turnip* is similar.